# What is Quentin Beck's real name?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home, mysterio

Part way through *Spider-Man: Far From Home* we get the reveal that...

> Mysterio is fake and it's all an illusion.

However, of note is that *Quentin Beck* is also a fake name as we learn when he thanks Guterman after getting Tony's glasses:

> **Quentin Beck:** To Guterman; **the story you created of a soldier from another Earth named Quentin** fighting space monsters in Europe is totally ridiculous, and apparently exactly the kind of thing people believe right now!
>
> <sub>*Spider-Man: Far From Home*</sub>

Of course it *had* to be a fake name as he was high up in Stark Industries and so his real name would have pulled into question the entire back story when he approached SHIELD.

So, do we know what Quentin Beck's real name actually is?

Comment: My money's on Bentin Queck.

Comment: This is something I've also been wondering about, we might not find out unless/until Mysterio returns. Until then, we can go with Bentin Queck.

Comment: *Launchpad McQuack*?

Answer (score 10):

This has been left intentionally unclear and *mysterious*. Jon Watts, the director, was asked this question directly and left it up for the viewer to decide what they felt was right.

Interestingly he does state *"he was able to mask himself and his background and change all of that"*. Now the two parts here, *"mask his background"* and *"change all of that"* are in contention. So he could have masked his background so it was hard for people to find out about a Quentin Beck who used to work for Stark Industries or he changed it and came up with a new name.

> **IGN: Is Quentin Beck actually his name, or is that a fake name? Because we were like, "How to no one check up on this guy and not notice that he worked for Tony?"**
>
> **Watts:** Some of these are deleted scenes as well, but you have to think that, in addition to all this technology he was using, that there was a way that he was able to mask himself and his background and change all of that. So, I think what's good about Mysterio that it doesn't all remain mysterious. There's a lot of questions at the end of the movie that are part of what makes Mysterio fun.
>
> **IGN: And, so I'm not mischaracterizing you, are you saying it's a deleted scene of kind of getting into how he's masking his identity?**
>
> **Watts:** There's a little bit more of like seeing behind the scenes of how they put everything together. But, it's just things that didn't make it for time. I want to see how people interpret it and see if people come up with what we can offer.
>
> <sub>[IGN, Spider-Man: Far From Home Director Jon Watts Answers All Our Biggest Questions](https://uk.ign.com/articles/2019/07/14/spider-man-far-from-home-director-full-spoilers-interview-ending-skrulls-explained)</sub>

Looking into the sentence used in the question by Mysterio himself the *"named Quentin"* part is totally redundant if he is talking about himself. I don't think we can infer *too much* from this but it does lend credence to this not being his own name.

If we look into the flashback of Beck when he was working for Stark Industries we only ever see him in a black suit with no name badge so that isn't overly helpful.

[image: Black and white close up of Beck in the flashback] [image: Profile of Beck in the flashback after hearing Tony named his creation BARF]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

The deleted scene Jon references above, if I'm looking right, is with Beck and his team in London. It shows them instructing people to film what happens and then making the fake shockwave. It then shows us Fury calling and his response to it and how good of an actor Beck is. Unfortunately, though this is just about how they got the whole plan to work but shows nothing of his backstory.

Answer (score 3):

The character name as given in credits, post film information and throughout the movie is Quentin Beck.

There is no reason to suspect that his name is not Quentin, the story that is created is about a character from another Earth, so having the same name as a person that happens to exist on the MCU Earth could be sold very easily. As could the fact that both work for Tony Stark, remember in our own stories and fiction we happily accept the idea of the same "person" existing in different versions of the same planet with slight differences in personality etc. You could imagine the dialogue:

> "Quentin Beck, we have our own one of them, a self opinionated egotistical scientists who has a history of mental issues but a brilliant brain" - Fury
>
> "It is so amazing how one life can be so different, that could have been me but for the love of my wife and the family she gave me, maybe once we are through this I can track him down and show him the man he could still become".  - Quentin

Also, and this cannot be understated, remember it is not Fury and Maria he is having to convince.

Comment: FWIW the reason to suspect it isn't his name is the quote in the question. Of course it could also be his name but as it is in the film the evidence more strongly points to it _not_ being it.

Comment: The Skrull part did cross my mind but remember he's not only revealing himself to them two but the whole world/SHIELD. It stands to reason that at least one other person would recognise the name of some talented scientist that used to work for Stark or would have done a background check.

Comment: I would argue the film evidence doesn't point to this, "a soldier from another earth named Quentin" as opposed to Quentin the fired Stark Employee who was mentally unstable. The quote can be taken several different ways.

Comment: The "named Quentin" is redundant though if that is his real name, it would be odd to say. For example, if I was saying it about myself I wouldn't say _"A solider from another Earth named TheLethalCarrot"_ but rather just simply _"A soldier from another Earth"_.

Comment: If he had a different name then you could expect that to be detailed somewhere either in the official Far from home script etc, or in the related material, the fact is that every official source states his name is Quentin Beck and it was Quentin Beck that was fired by Stark Industries. Quentin would not be the first, or the last villain to talk about themselves in the 3rd person.

Comment: I've found an interview where the director, Jon Watts, said it's been left intentionally ambiguous, along with several other things about Beck. What official sources are you getting your information from and has the official script been released? I can't remember ever seeing that?

Comment: Just looking now through everything to see where I saw that but if you have found a source where the director states it is ambiguous then that is probably a better answer then anything that is based in part on opinion

Comment: This video here the writers talk about the idea of the Multiverse and Beck is a con artist pulling off a massive con, it isn't specific but again they talk about Beck as the character in the film not a pseudonym for a different person. 
https://www.gamespot.com/articles/spider-man-far-from-homes-writers-answer-burning-q/1100-6468408/

Comment: Fair enough, I don't think that's too clear because they'll obviously use a name the audience is familiar with. I'm not ruling out the possibility of it being his actual name but after more research I don't think we have enough evidence either way to say for sure what it is at this point.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, now I'm scared of a militant lethal carrot from another Earth coming to kill me.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: To me, the "named Quentin" feels forced in either event. Everyone there _knows_ the hero they created is called Quentin, it's there purely for the audience's benefit, so we know without a doubt that he's talking about the character he's playing, not someone else. So I'm not sure how much it helps in this instance. Having said that, if he did use his own name, I wonder why the super paranoid Fury didn't at least go check there was a doppleganger still out there (although I guess his being off-world could be a hand-wavey explanation).

Comment: It isnt fury, that is the wole point, Talos is embarressed he got caught out by Beck and almost lost EDITH and doesn't want to call Fury to let him know. So therefore he isn't as paranoid as Fury